# script not working when arguments used from argparse rather than defaults

Tags: python

I have tried to write a python script to extract zip files, copy to a directory and create PR. The default behaviour is to use no arguments and just use the defaults. When I do this it works perfectly. However when I pass the arguments `-z` or `-f` I get the following error:

```
235: An error occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ops.eekfonky/code/dev/server/trunk/deployment/./templatesToPR.py", line 217, in main
    template_name, filename = unzip_templates(zip_dir, extraction_dir)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/ops.eekfonky/code/dev/server/trunk/deployment/./templatesToPR.py", line 57, in unzip_templates
    filename = next(f for f in os.listdir(zip_dir) if f.endswith('.zip'))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
StopIteration
```

Here is the full script;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import logging
import os
import shutil
import sys
import subprocess
import importlib
import tempfile
import uuid
import zipfile
import git
import re
from git import Repo, GitCommandError

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(lineno)d: %(message)s")

# Define default values in a dictionary
DEFAULTS = {
    "default_branch": "release/17",
    "zip_dir": "~/Downloads/templates",
}

def parse_arguments():
    """Parses command-line arguments."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='''
    This script handles git repositories and templates based on internal defaults or command-line overrides.
    Use command-line options to specify custom settings for the script's operation.''')
    parser.add_argument('--def-branch', '-d', default=DEFAULTS["default_branch"],
                        help='Default git branch name. Default is "%(default)s".')
    parser.add_argument('--zip-dir', '-z', default=DEFAULTS["zip_dir"],
                        help='Directory for zipped templates. Default is "%(default)s".')
    parser.add_argument('--zip_file', '-f', type=str, default=None, nargs = '?',
                        help='Specify the .zip filename explicitly. Defaults to the zip_dir if not specified.')
    return parser.parse_args()

def install_and_import(package, module_name=None):
    """Installs a package if needed and imports it."""
    module_name = module_name if module_name else package
    try:
        importlib.import_module(module_name)
    except ImportError:
        subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])
        importlib.import_module(module_name)

def ensure_directory_exists(directory):
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)

def unzip_templates(zip_dir, extraction_path):
    """Extracts a template ZIP, handling 'email' and 'sms' directories and preserving nested structures."""
    zip_file_path = None

    if os.path.isdir(zip_dir):
        filename = next(f for f in os.listdir(zip_dir) if f.endswith('.zip'))
        zip_file_path = os.path.join(zip_dir, filename)
    else:
        filename = os.path.basename(zip_dir)
        zip_file_path = zip_dir

    if not filename:
        raise FileNotFoundError("No ZIP file found in the directory or provided file")

    template_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]  # Determine template_name

    # Rename template_name if it has spaces (optional)
    base_name, ext = os.path.splitext(template_name)
    if ' ' in base_name:
        new_base_name = base_name.replace(' ', '-')
        template_name = new_base_name + ext

    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
        # Check for files with spaces in the name
        for zip_info in zip_ref.infolist():
            if ' ' in zip_info.filename:
                raise ValueError(f"ZIP file contains a file with a space in the name: {zip_info.filename}")

        # Extract directly into the extraction_path
        zip_ref.extractall(extraction_path)

    # Cleanup __MACOSX Directory
    macosx_dir = os.path.join(extraction_path, '__MACOSX')
    if os.path.exists(macosx_dir) and os.path.isdir(macosx_dir):
        shutil.rmtree(macosx_dir)

    logging.info(f"Extracted {filename} to {extraction_path}")
    return template_name, filename

def copy_templates_to_destination(extraction_dir, template_dir):
    """Copies extracted templates, overwrites matching files, adds new files, and skips hidden files."""

    for subdir in os.listdir(extraction_dir):
        source_dir = os.path.join(extraction_dir, subdir)
        destination_dir = os.path.join(template_dir, subdir)

        # Filter out any hidden files before copying
        non_hidden_files = [f for f in os.listdir(source_dir) if not f.startswith('.')]

        # Copy with merge
        shutil.copytree(source_dir, destination_dir, ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns('.*'), dirs_exist_ok=True)
        logging.info(f"Merged {subdir} into {destination_dir}")

def cleanup(extraction_dir, args, filename=None):
    """Clean up temporary files and optionally the original ZIP file(s)."""

    shutil.rmtree(extraction_dir)
    logging.info(f"Temporary files cleaned up from {extraction_dir}")

    zip_dir = DEFAULTS["zip_dir"]
    zip_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(zip_dir))
    original_zip_file = os.path.join(zip_dir, filename)

    if os.path.isfile(original_zip_file):
        os.remove(original_zip_file)
        logging.debug(f"Original ZIP file removed: {original_zip_file}")
    else:
        logging.warning(f"No {filename} for ZIP file deletion in default handling.")


class GitRepoManager:
    def __init__(self, repo_path):
        self.repo = Repo(repo_path)

    def prepare_and_create_branch(self, default_branch, template_name, user_initials):
        """Prepares the repository  and creates a new branch for template updates."""
        original_branch = self.repo.active_branch.name
        unique_suffix = str(uuid.uuid4())[:8]
        new_branch = f"{user_initials}/{template_name}-{unique_suffix}-no-build"
        stashed_changes = False

        try:
            if self.repo.is_dirty():
                logging.info("Changes detected in the working directory. Attempting to stash changes...")
                self.repo.git.stash('save', "Stashing changes before template update")
                logging.info("All changes stashed.")
                stashed_changes = True

            self.repo.git.checkout(default_branch)
            self.repo.git.pull()
            self.repo.git.checkout("HEAD", b=new_branch)
            logging.info(f"New branch '{new_branch}' created from '{default_branch}'.")

            return True, new_branch, original_branch, stashed_changes

        except git.exc.GitCommandError as e:
            logging.error(f"Error preparing repository or creating branch: {e}")
            return False, None, None, stashed_changes

    def handle_updates(self, template_dir, branch_name, original_branch, stashed_changes):
        """Stages, commits, and pushes template changes"""
        try:
            if branch_name not in self.repo.git.branch().split():
                sys.exit(f"Branch '{branch_name}' does not exist locally. Cannot proceed with push.")
            self.repo.git.add(template_dir)
            self.repo.index.commit("Update templates")
            subprocess.run(["git", "push", "origin", branch_name, "--progress"])
            self.repo.git.checkout(original_branch)
            if stashed_changes:
                self.repo.git.stash('pop')
            self.repo.git.branch('-D', branch_name)
            logging.info(f"Templates pushed and local branch '{branch_name}' removed.")
        except git.exc.GitCommandError as e:
            logging.error(f"Git operations failed: {e}")

    def backup_current_state(self):
        # Create a temporary branch to hold the current state
        try:
            self.repo.git.branch('temp_backup_branch')
        except GitCommandError:
            # Branch already exists, force update it
            self.repo.git.branch('-D', 'temp_backup_branch')
            self.repo.git.branch('temp_backup_branch')

    def rollback_to_backup(self):
        try:
            # Reset the current branch to the backup branch
            self.repo.git.reset('--hard', 'temp_backup_branch')
            print("Rollback successful.")
        except GitCommandError as e:
            print(f"Rollback failed: {e}")

def main():
    args = parse_arguments()
    install_and_import('GitPython', 'git')
    from git import Repo, GitCommandError

    # Script variables with argparse and dynamic paths
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    os.chdir(script_dir)
    git_repo_root = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(script_dir, "../../../"))  # Example path
    template_dir = os.path.join(git_repo_root, "server/trunk/services/src/main/resources/templates")

    if args.zip_dir:
        zip_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(args.zip_dir))  # Ensure absolute path with ~ expansion
        if not os.path.isdir(zip_dir):
            raise ValueError("Error: When using the -z flag, you must provide a directory containing ZIP files.")

    elif args.zip_file:
        zip_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(args.zip_file))  # Ensure absolute path with ~ expansion
        if not os.path.isfile(zip_dir):
            raise ValueError("Error: When using the -f flag, you must provide a valid file path to a ZIP file.")
    else:
        zip_dir = DEFAULTS["zip_dir"]
        zip_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(zip_dir))

    default_branch = args.def_branch
    ensure_directory_exists(zip_dir)
    extraction_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix='templates-extraction-', dir='/tmp')

    try:
        if len(zip_dir) == 0:
            print("Empty directory or file not found")
            raise Exception('zip template dir is empty')

        template_name, filename = unzip_templates(zip_dir, extraction_dir)
        print(f"template name: {template_name}, filename: {filename}")
        repo_manager = GitRepoManager(git_repo_root)
        # Calculate user_initials
        whoami_output = subprocess.check_output(['whoami']).decode('utf-8').strip()
        parts = whoami_output.split('.')
        user_initials = parts[1][0] + parts[-1][0]  # Extract initials from first and last name
        success, branch_name, original_branch, stashed_changes = repo_manager.prepare_and_create_branch(default_branch, template_name, user_initials)
        if not success:
            logging.error("Failed to create the new branch. Aborting script.")
            sys.exit(1)
        copy_templates_to_destination(extraction_dir, template_dir)
        repo_manager.handle_updates(template_dir, branch_name, original_branch, stashed_changes)

        # removes everything from templates dir
        if success:
            cleanup(extraction_dir, args, filename)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        repo_manager.backup_current_state()
        repo_manager.rollback_to_backup()

# Call your main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Why is this error happening? I am new to Python so am stuck

Answer (score -1):

The problem is this line of code:

```
filename = next(f for f in os.listdir(zip_dir) if f.endswith('.zip'))
```

When there are no matching files, this raises a `StopIteration` error. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

> ```
> next(iterator)
> next(iterator, default)
> ```
>
> Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its `__next__()` method. If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise `StopIteration` is raised.

A simple solution would be to catch the `StopIeration` error:

```py
def unzip_templates(zip_dir, extraction_path):
    """Extracts a template ZIP, handling 'email' and 'sms' directories and preserving nested structures."""
    zip_file_path = None
    filename = None

    if os.path.isdir(zip_dir):
        try:
            filename = next(f for f in os.listdir(zip_dir) if f.endswith('.zip'))
            zip_file_path = os.path.join(zip_dir, filename)
        except StopIeration:
            pass
    else:
        filename = os.path.basename(zip_dir)
        zip_file_path = zip_dir

    if not filename:
        raise FileNotFoundError("No ZIP file found in the directory or provided file")
```

You can avoid the `StopIeration` exception by using the two-argument form of `next`:

```py
filename = next((f for f in os.listdir(zip_dir) if f.endswith('.zip')), None)
```

This will set `filename` to `None` if there are no `.zip` files. However, for this to work, you'll need to modify your logic a bit (because otherwise the subsequent `os.path.join` will fail if `filename` is `None`). Maybe something like:

```py
def unzip_templates(zip_dir, extraction_path):
    """Extracts a template ZIP, handling 'email' and 'sms' directories and preserving nested structures."""
    zip_file_path = None

    if not zip_dir:
        raise ValueError("zip_dir must contain a path")

    if os.path.isdir(zip_dir):
        filename = next((f for f in os.listdir(zip_dir) if f.endswith(".zip")), None)
        if not filename:
            raise FileNotFoundError(
                "No ZIP file found in the directory or provided file"
            )

        zip_file_path = os.path.join(zip_dir, filename)
    else:
        filename = os.path.basename(zip_dir)
        zip_file_path = zip_dir

    template_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]  # Determine template_name

    ...
```